# "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member" error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++

I have this function:

```
std::string Room::getUsersAsString(std::vector<User*> usersList, User * excludeUser)
{
    std::string usersNames = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++) {
        if (usersList[i]->getUsername() != excludeUser->getUsername) {
            usersNames.append(usersList[i]->getUsername);
            usersNames.append(" ");
        }
    }

    return usersNames;
}
```

Whenever I try to run the program, I get the following error:

> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

How can I fix it?

Comment: Typo: `excludeUser->getUsername` should be `excludeUser->getUsername()`.

Comment: Are you missing `()` from the end of `getUsername`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you use

```
if (usersList[i]->getUsername() != excludeUser->getUsername)
```

instead of

```
if (usersList[i]->getUsername() != excludeUser->getUsername())
```

your compiler will think you want to use a function pointer instead of the method itself, and if you would have wanted to use a function pointer, you would still have to get the address of it (using &).

So make sure you don't forget your () after a function call!

Answer (score 12):

You are missing the function call parentheses in these lines:

```
if (usersList[i]->getUsername() != excludeUser->getUsername) {
```

and

```
usersNames.append(usersList[i]->getUsername);
```

Try changing them into this:

```
if (usersList[i]->getUsername() != excludeUser->getUsername()) {
```

and

```
usersNames.append(usersList[i]->getUsername());
```