# How do I fix this Class Code that has a syntax error

Tags: c++, class, syntax-error

I'm currently very new to programming, I've just learned about classes so I tried to create a basic public class that would allow me to print a text in the console... pretty much the cout command but when debugging the program I was prompted with this error.

> ***"error C3867: 'ChandlersClass::randomText': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"***

Here is the code that I used for the class:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ChandlersClass
{
public:
    void randomText()
    {
        cout << "Random text is right here" << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    ChandlersClass chandlersObject;
    chandlersObject.randomText;
    return 0;
}
```

This is all of the code that I have right now and I don't see any error colors or underlines throughout it so I'm not really sure how to fix it, also being new I'm not too familiar with the & use, I've seen other programmers use it and use a funny name but I just don't know the purpose and how I could fix this.

Comment: you forgot to add () at end of the function call to randomText.

Comment: Function call syntax has a `()` at the end. `chandlersObject.randomText();`

Comment: Potential dupes found by googling "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477997/non-standard-syntax-use-to-create-a-pointer-to-member-error-vs2015/38478203 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845585/c-visual-studio-non-standard-syntax-use-to-create-a-pointer-to-member https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815641/visual-studio-2015-non-standard-syntax-use-to-create-a-pointer-to-member

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of function call is wrong in the above code.

The correct syntax for calling a member function of a class through its object variable is:
**objectName.functionName();**

In the above case:
**chandlersObject.randomText();** //You missed the parentheses

Comment: [Braces vs Brackets vs Parenthesis](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/parentheses.html).